# вложенные циклы

Tags: php

В данном случае главный цикл выполняется единожды, второй цикл выполняется трижды (соответственно выводится 3 итема ). А в вот в цикле `for` который для каждого итема должен выполнятся 5 раз , выполняется 15 раз (я понимаю что он вложенный именно здесь он правильно выполняется 15 раз ), но как сделать так, что бы для каждого итема он выполнялся индивидуально 5 раз.Голову сломал , но не могу понять где этот цикл должен реализованным быть

```
 foreach($_SESSION['name'] as $cat => $value){ 
//выбор по названию итема
    foreach ($value as $id => $v){ 
// выбор по ид итема
//выборка из бд по рейтингу (общее количество рейтинга делим на количество голосов )
      for ($i=0;i<5;i++){ 
         $star_rating_recall .= '<span id="active_star_'.$i.'" class="passive_star '.$active_star.'"></span>';
      }
$content . = 'html '.$star_rating_recall.' html ' ;
    }    
}
```

Comment: Глядя на комментарий в коде `выборка из бд по рейтингу` предположу, что проще сделать нормальную адекватную выборку из БД для начала. А потом вывести эти данные слегка подправив, если это будет необходимо

Comment: Что значит "_для каждого итема он выполнялся индивидуально 5 раз_"? Он итак выполняется для каждого "итема" ровно пять раз. В чем проблема-то?

Comment: Попробуйте вот такую выборку, чтобы не делать уйму запросов на каждую оценку `SELECT
  rate,
  COUNT(*) AS c
FROM
  rating
GROUP BY
  rate`

Comment: в таблице рейтинга заносится айди итема, и сколько по 5 баллам оценен итем, поэтому другого варианта кроме делить количество голосов для каждого итема на количество голосов по айди итема, я не вижу

Comment: поправил в вопросе общий вид. И суть в том что этих самых `span`для 1 итема вставляет 5 . для 2го итема вставляет 10 раз , для 3го -15 и тд

Comment: @drik Если он вставляет для одного итема 15 строк, значит `foreach ($value as $id => $v)` выдает этот итем 3 раза. Без вариантов. Приведите в вопросе содержимое вашего $value.

Answer (score 1):

переменную что объявлена в цикле `for`  нужно обновлять по ее значению, то бишь перед циклом `$star_rating_recall = ""`